# Bootstrap add custom css at breakpoint

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

For example

```
<div class="col-md-my">
</div>
```

```
.xx {
   color: black;
}

.yy {
   color: red;
}
```

Just like bootstrap change width at breakpoint.

Set new class `col-md-my`

When its width is over md breakpoint, css add class `xx`

When its width is under md breakpoint, css add class `yy`

`xx` and `yy` is custom css.

How do add by bootstrap variable and function

Comment: Look up the actual breakpoints in Bootstrap docs and/or web, then add/remove your class using js/jquery at those exact widths. Or use *media queries*. That's the proper way of styling based on device width. It's a similar approach. Tons of resources online.

Answer (score 0):

**Information:**

### Anything in this query (anything before 576px):

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { 

  .custom-txt-color {color: #000000;}

}
```

### ..will be black *(#000000)*

---

---

### When it reaches 576px:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { 

  .custom-txt-color {color: #666000;}

}
```

### ..it will become dark green *(#666000)*

---

---

**If no max-width** is declared it remains:

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { 

  .custom-txt-color {color: #000000;}

}
```

.....text is black and then:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) { 

  .custom-txt-color {color: #666000;}

}
```

.....now it is dark green and stays dark green, because there is no max width.

[A practical tool for testing screen sizes<<<<](http://responsivetesttool.com)

**Usable breakpoint snippet:** [(directly from Bootstrap 4.6)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints):

```css
/* Extra small devices  (portrait phones, less than 576px) */
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

/* Small devices  (landscape phones, 576px and up) */
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

/* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```